# C# closed XML library with .net core 3.1.1 - works when debugging but not when compiled

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, closedxml

when I run code via visual studio (IIS Express) it runs fine and exports xl spreadsheet.

```
var wb = new XLWorkbook();
var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Sheet1");
wb.SaveAs(fileName);
```

However when I compile and run on either IIS or IIS Express (on exactly same machine), I get the error

```
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\...'
```

Very wierd!

Comment: The error message means the application couldn't find the path 'C:\...'. Could you please post more codes which line you faced this error and what's the file path you have saved in the server. Does this path is existing on the server?

Comment: Yes it does exist on server; as I said the code works perfectly when debugging on the very same server

Comment: Debugging and the production environment is not the same, we need to know more details codes and information, then we could know why it throw this error,

Comment: Maybe your IIS user does not have permissions for the path and does not see it. (And your own user has them, so it works from VS.)