# Issue using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel: Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, office-interop, excel-interop

I have built a web app using .net core 3.1.1, and downloaded Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel from Nuget.
Reason I am not using ClosedXML as it is not working when compiled...see
[link to stackO post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60663348/c-sharp-closed-xml-library-with-net-core-3-1-1-works-when-debugging-but-not-w)

Nuget package is described as follows:

```
This the assembly necessary to do Office 2013 Excel interop
Version:  15.0.4795.1000
```

Below is error I am getting:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0
```

Below is my code

```
public static void exportToExcel1(DataTable dt, string fileName)
        {
            XL.Application app = new XL.Application();
            app.DisplayAlerts = false;

            try
            {
                XL.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
                XL.Worksheet ws = (XL.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];

                // export column headers
                for (int colNdx = 0; colNdx < dt.Columns.Count; colNdx++)
                {
                    ws.Cells[1, colNdx + 1] = dt.Columns[colNdx].ColumnName;
                }

                // export data
                for (int rowNdx = 0; rowNdx < dt.Rows.Count; rowNdx++)
                {
                    for (int colNdx = 0; colNdx < dt.Columns.Count; colNdx++)
                    {
                        ws.Cells[rowNdx + 2, colNdx + 1] = (dt.Rows[rowNdx][colNdx]).ToString();
                    }
                }

                //ws.Columns.AutoFit();

                wb.SaveAs(fileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XL.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                wb.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            }
            finally
            {
                app.Quit();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The NuGet package you’ve linked to only provides interoperability between your code and the Office .dll. You still need to install MS Office on the computer and configure your code so that it can find the library.

You should also note that Microsoft does not support or recommend using Office in this manner. It can cause all sorts of performance issues or even cause your web server process to hang.

Answer (score 1):

This error happens because you are using Nuget to use the library. Do not use Nuget, use COM Microsoft Excel (or Word, etc) 16.0 (or other version) Object Library.

[image]

Comment: provide more detail and clarity. paste image instead of attachment